# Javascript window onblur firing when clicking facebook like button

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, onblur

I have a popup that displays some content and a facebook like button.  The popup closes on window.onblur.  When I click on the facebook button though, it treats it as a blur event and closes the popup without ever liking it.  What can I do?

Here is my facebook button code as per the facebook instructions (also has meta data in header):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";

      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }

(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial"></div>
```

and my initial onblur:

```
    <script> 
         setTimeout(setOnBlur,500);  
          function setOnBlur(){window.onblur = closeWin;}  
          function closeWin(e){window.close();}  
</script>
```

Either what am I doing wrong that clicking on the facebook div tag triggers an on blur event, or how can I make it so it doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook `like` button is usually wrapped into iframe. Focusing another iframe makes current window blur. AFAIR, there's a way include Facebook like button not as iframe. Couldn't remember how do that, though.

In order to ignore focus lost to some iframe (not sure, this will work)

```
window.onblur = function(e) {
    var t = e.target;
    if ((t.window == t) // this is a window
     && (t != window)) // but some other window
        return true;
    closeWin();
}
```

Comment: Well facebook gives you options for html5 and iframe, and the above code is the html5 version.  I figured the iframe version would definitely hit the onblur, though

Comment: Hmm. And what is `arguments[0].target` in onblur callback?

Comment: When supplying the onblur with a function (closeWin) and placing this code in it: function closeWin(e){alert(arguments[0].target);  }         I get Object DomWindow

Comment: And what is `e.location.href`?

Comment: My apologies, e.location.href doesn't return anything it seems.  It doesn't even send a blank alert

Comment: Most possibly this is due to security restriction. One can't normally read anything from window of another URL. Looks like this is a frame )

Comment: Yea I confirmed that by alerting document.activeElement.nodeName, and it came back IFRAME in chrome.  Interestingly enough, it comes back as BODY in firefox, which means I can't just use an if statement detecting if its an iframe and not closing it.... do i have any options though?

Comment: You may compare that `Object DomWindow` to the current window. If not equal, this is an iframe and just ignore that event (`return true;`)

Comment: Through a simple compare ?  (if(arguments[0].target == window))?  That is always equal when I test that'

Comment: Yes. But you'll need to check, this is actually a window in code too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8604/discussion-between-kirilloid-and-nick)

Answer (score 0):

U'll need to check this out - `event.stopPropogation()`

Event bubbling happens and u need to handle it.

Comment: Where does it need to be handled...?  If I call it before the window.close() then the popup doesn't close.  If I call it after, then it closes before it stops bubbling.  And I don't see very many other places to "handle" it